# How to reload a bak of etc/apache2/httpd.conf in terminal after bad changes made with Vim?

Tags: macos, vim, apache-http-server

I changed the apache2/httpd.conf through vim in Terminal OS X yosémite as Su and quit saving changes. But in browser, the localhost sent the 403 Forbidden message "you don't have permission access to this server". Must have done something wrong but I followed exactly these steps:

/Users/catherinelegna/Desktop/Capture d’écran 2015-05-15 à 15.20.03.png

I had backup the file do previously with command "cp http.conf http.conf.bak
How can I reload the bak file to restore it?
Thanks for your help

Comment: whelp, you need to upload that image, not drag it :P

Comment: @TD.512 is saying that "/Users/catherinelegna/Desktop/Capture d’écran 2015-05-15 à 15.20.03.png" doesn't do us any good. Please edit your question and replace that line with the image itself. Or upload the image to an image-sharing site and link to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ya are:

```
rm httpd.conf;cp httpd.conf.bak httpd.conf
```

Simple as that. remove, replace, and then you'll have to reload apache2

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will do that but first I must understand what I did wrong and reread my wrong changes. One always learn from errors ;-))

Comment: Well it's worse that I thought. Now when trying to enable root mode in Terminal it doesn't get me to <root#> but to <sh-3.2#>. I post another question in order to upload the things I did

Comment: sh-3.2# is a root terminal, 'cept you're using `sh` and not `bash` type `bash` and you should be all good

Comment: that `#` you see signifies root. if it were this: `$` you wouldn't be root

Comment: You mean just type bash after  sh-3.2#?

Comment: enter at least 15 characters... yes

Comment: I just changed the RootDocument and the <Directory> line, changing /Library/WebServer/Documents to /Users/myname/htdocs (a directory I created in my Home directory

Comment: ok, do you want to copy the old file across? BTW, I suspect Apache2 isn't able to access  that directory

Comment: I am finally in  ~/root# (forgot the - after su before) So now I am able to return to the etc/apache2 directory. A question: your command rm httpd.conf cp http.conf.bak http.conf where when do I type it? Am a real new

Comment: do `ls` on the `/etc/apache2` wherever `httpd.conf` and `httpd.conf.bak` are is where you want to do that command

Comment: As I had only changed two lines. I tried in vim to edit (i) those lines and changed it to the old state. Save (:w) and quit (:q) But still the same 403 error in localhost.

Comment: Thanks to TD.512 it worked fine. I will think twice before changing my apache directory now

Answer (score 0):

Inside Vim, you can do this via:

```
:%delete _ | read %.bak | 1delete _
```

The `%` refers to the current file name. This is convenient if you still have Vim open, and safer than direct overriding in the shell because you still need to explicitly `:write` the changes, and have Vim's undo system.

Comment: but rm and cping back are still safe